# how to add a javascript alert with a PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript

let's say i have an input form, wherein, it's use for an email address. this form is part of a long form so i use an alert box instead when other inputs got errors....my question now is, if I checked the email input string via php, if it has been taken , how will I put the message like e.g "this email has been taken" in an alert box if i am using PHP to check it from backend ?..i want an alert box, since I use it with the other input boxes that don't need a backend check
e.g

```
alert("$errormessage");
```

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript">alert('<?php echo $errorMessage ?>')</script> Where echo $errorMessage is your dynamic php errormessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can echo any kind of javascript with PHP. The question is however, are you sure you want to do this? You can also do like this:

```
<?php if(emailExists): ?>
<script>alert('Email exists!')</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But you could also use jQuery and Ajax requests to check if email exists with ajax when user has typed the email.

Comment: the problem with ajax in jquery,is, i dunno how to use it...i hafta to learn it over the weekend, as of now,i just wanted to make the form work with an alert box :(

Answer (score 5):

PHP is server-side language. you can output it to user with

```
echo "<script>alert('".mysql_real_escape_string($errormessage)."');</script>";
```

or you can write your own function

```
function alert($a){
    echo "<script>alert('".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."');</script>";

}

alert("test");
```

Comment: Please show your support by [accepting my answer via button showed on image](http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<script>alert("ssss");</script>' ;`  just put it within echo it will work that way