# Block unauthorized user from access specific pages (PHP)

Tags: php

As I'm new to PHP. I have a questions about how to block unauthorized users from accessing the specific pages.
As from my assignments, I have to write a function to block some types of users.

Assume that,

1.Logged Normal Users have an authorization number as "NULL"

2.Normal Employees have an authorization number as "1"

3.Authorized Employees have an authorization number as "2"

4.Department Managers have an authorization number as "3"

5.HR Managers have an authorization number as "4"

This is my code in this page so far, which I have no idea what type of codes I have to added and where in this page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
header("Location: login.php");  
?>

<div class="clearfix colelem" id="u4470"><!-- group -->
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1609-4"><!-- content -->
  <p><span id="u1609">Recruiting</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu5139"><!-- group -->
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u5139"><!-- group -->
  <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame grpelem" id="u4533" href="department-manager-tab.php"><!-- image --><img class="block" id="u4533_img" src="images/pasted%20image%202650x1756.jpg" alt="" width="510" height="341"/></a>
  <a class="nonblock nontext clearfix grpelem" id="u4555-4" href="department-manager-tab.html"><!-- content --><p>Proceed as Department Manager</p></a>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u5140"><!-- group -->
  <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame grpelem" id="u4547" href="hr-tab.php"><!-- image --><img class="block" id="u4547_img" src="images/how-to-hire-a-great-social-media-manager.jpg" alt="" width="510" height="341"/></a>
  <a class="nonblock nontext clearfix grpelem" id="u4556-4" href="hr-tab.html"><!-- content --><p>Proceed as HR Staff</p></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

User type 1 ("NULL") and type 2 (authorization number as "1") should not able to access this page.

How can I do it?
Thank you in advance.

Ps. Codes maybe a little bit mess due to the codes are exported from adobe muse
Ps2. If there are something that it should helps but it didn't tagged, they are also welcome.

Comment: you need to 1) log them in. 2) store their access level in a session. 3) check that when you load a page and do something according to the result of the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a condition to the start of your script.

Assuming the authorisation level is a session variable, you could add something like the below to your code;

```
<?php

if($_SESSION['authLevel'] == NULL || $_SESSION['authLevel'] == 1) {
    // Do something (A redirect for example)
    exit;
}

?>
```

More information can be found here;

Sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

*if* construct: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comparison operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: What if I want to popup the alert message before redirect those users?

Comment: @gznero Take a look at the JS function `alert()` - This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6871517/4781925

Comment: @gznero Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of

```
<?php

session_start();

//Permission groups allowed on page
$access = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    header("Location: login.php");
}

if(in_array($_SESSION['AuthLevel'], $access) == false){
    //Redirect to universally accessed page
    header("Location: index.php"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: This is also a good way of doing it, the access array allows for easier change in the future